# Unable to volume mount docker postgres on podman machine

Tags: postgresql, docker, podman

Getting started with podman and I wanted to run docker postgres with a volume mount to the current directly FS.

Following along the official documenation on postgres regarding storage:

- https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/postgres/README.md#pgdata
- https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/postgres/README.md#where-to-store-data

After initializing and starting the podman machine I pull the docker postgres and run the following command from the above documentation:

```
$ podman run -d \
    --name some-postgres \
    -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword \
    -e PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata \
    -v ${PWD}/pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
    postgres
```

and I get this error: `chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata': Operation not permitted`

On my laptop the folder in question, `pgdata` has these permissions: `drwxrwxrwx`

When I do a `podman machine ssh` and check that podman also see the same permissions: `drwxrwxrwx.`

I have tried different variations of the above the `run` command but still unable to run the example in the documentation to mount the FS.

Is this not suppose to work readily? Is there more permissions that are missing? What is the 'best' approach to mount the volume? I know I can create a `podman volume` but that doesn't use the data folder in the project.

--another attempt--

```
podman run \
  --name local \
  -e POSTGRES_DB=mypostgres \
  -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres \
  -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres \
  -e PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata \
  -v ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
  -p 5432:5432 \
  --user postgres \
  postgres:16.1-alpine
```

--another attempt--

```
podman run \
  --name local \
  -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres \
  -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres \
  -v ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
  --userns=keep-id:uid=999,gid=999 \
  postgres:16.1-alpine
```

which returns and then hangs on disk sync:

```
chmod: /var/run/postgresql: Operation not permitted 
...
performing post-bootstrap initialization ... 
sh: locale: not found 
2023-12-05 16:14:57.040 UTC [17] WARNING:  no usable system locales were found 
ok 
syncing data to disk ...
```

--another attempt--

```
podman run \
  --name local \
  -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres \
  -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres \
  -v ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
  --userns=keep-id:uid=999,gid=999 \
  --user 0:0 \
  postgres:16.1-alpine
```

which returns

```
find: /var/lib/postgresql/data: Permission denied
chown: /var/lib/postgresql/data: Operation not permitted
```

Running on OSX M3 Sonoma &  `podman machine info`

```
Version:
  APIVersion: 4.8.0
  Built: 1701101318
  BuiltTime: Mon Nov 27 10:08:38 2023
  GitCommit: c4dfcf14874479e34b3f312f089fc5840e306258
  GoVersion: go1.21.4
  Os: darwin
  OsArch: darwin/arm64
  Version: 4.8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the command-line option `--userns=keep-id:uid=999,gid=999`
This option maps UIDs and GIDs so that the container user 999:999 is mapped to your regular user on the host.

See also:
https://github.com/eriksjolund/podman-detect-option#example-3-use-detected-option-when-running-postgres-on-macos

(I don't know if **--user** should be used. If it works with `--user postgres` use that)

Comment: Running this on rootless per the docs you shared: `podman run --name local -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -v ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data --userns=keep-id:uid=999,gid=999 postgres:16.1-alpine`. Immediately I get this: `chmod: /var/run/postgresql: Operation not permitted` The database keeps initializing but then hangs on this: `performing post-bootstrap initialization ... sh: locale: not found
2023-12-05 16:14:57.040 UTC [17] WARNING:  no usable system locales were found
ok
syncing data to disk ...` it never finishes syncing

Comment: Does it work if you add the option `--user 0:0`

Comment: I get: `find: /var/lib/postgresql/data: Permission denied
chown: /var/lib/postgresql/data: Operation not permitted`

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue with mounting the volume in Podman, you can use the -e **PGDATA=./pgdata** in the Podman command.
This will set the PGDATA environment variable to a path within the container that Podman has permission to access.